# Do failed CUDA memory allocations require a cudaDeviceReset call?

Tags: cuda, cuda-context

When a CUDA runtime API call for GPU memory allocation fails, is it necessary to reset the context using a call to `cudaDeviceReset()`?

Comment: No. Fifteen characters.

Comment: @talonmies yet again, thank you :)